# Two (nearly) Identical C# / Entity Framework Button-Click handlers behaving differently

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

This is only my second post, please forgive any protocol errors.

I have two `Button-Click` handlers that are almost copy & paste images but have behavior differences that are causing issues (and frustration)

Both are adding new child records to an employee database (`Entity Framework 6, Code First`), one a new Phone Number the other a Position.

Phone Number:

```
private void btn_NewRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (thisNumber != null)
    {
        DbEntityEntry entry = _fDBC.Entry(thisNumber);

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
               //  PROMPT to Save or Cancel current modified record
        }
    }

    EmployeePhoneNumber newNumber = new EmployeePhoneNumber();
    newNumber.EmployeeID = thisEmployee.EmployeeID;
    int highestKey = _fDBC.EmployeePhoneNumbers          //  This is the only difference between these two Handlers,  
                                                         //  Phone Numbers use a non-automated multi-part Key
                          .Where(a => a.EmployeeID == thisEmployee.EmployeeID)
                          .Select(a => a.EmployeePhoneNumberID)
                          .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)                       // Default if set IS EMPTY
                          .Max();

    newNumber.EmployeePhoneNumberID = highestKey + 1;

    try
    {
        _fDBC.EmployeePhoneNumbers.Add(newNumber);

        // INITIALIZING the Validation Checklist here
    }
    catch (DuplicateKeyException ex)
    {
         //  Not getting any exceptions
    }

    bs_EmployeePhoneNumbers.MoveLast();       //  This works fine for the new PhoneNumber
                                              //  The binding source sees the new record and moves to it,
                                              //  the new record is displayed on the Form.
    thisNumber = newNumber;
}
```

This Code adds a new Phone Number to the Context, moves to it, and on return the new (blank) record is displayed on the form ready to be filled out.

Now the weirdness

Position:

```
private void btn_NewPosition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (thisPosition != null)
    {
        DbEntityEntry entry = _fDBC.Entry(thisPosition);

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
                 // PROMPT to save or cancel current, modified record.
        }
    }

    EmployeePosition newPos = new EmployeePosition();
    newPos.EmployeeID = thisEmployee.EmployeeID;               
    newPos.StartDate = DateTime.Today;

    try
    {
        _fDBC.EmployeePositions.Add(newPos);

        // INITIALIZING the Validation checklist here

    }
    catch (DuplicateKeyException ex)
    {
           //  Not getting any exceptions
    }

    bs_EmployeePos.MoveLast();       //  This Code does NOT work. 
                                     //  The bindingsource does NOT see the new record, the move has no effect, 
                                     //  and the current (existing) record is displayed on the form.
    thisPosition = newPos;

}
```

This code does create a new record, it can be seen in the debugger.
The Bindingsource just does not see it.

The question is 'Why does one work and the other does not?'

Again, the only difference between these handlers is the LINQ query in the Phone Number handler to find the sub-index value for the new record.  That query occurs (obviously) before the ADD instruction.

I can work around this by redefining the Position Bindingsource's DataSource just prior to the move:

```
bs_EmployeePos.DataSource = thisEmployee.EmployeePositions.Where(ep => ep.EndDate == null).ToList();
```

But this causes other problems- It prevents my [Cancel] button handler from working successfully.

Any ideas?

Thanks.
Ross

Addition: Definition of EmployeePhoneNumber & EmployeePosition:

```
public partial class EmployeePosition
{
    public int EmployeePositionID { get; set; }

    public int PositionID { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public int PayrollClassID { get; set; }

    public int? InterviewerID { get; set; }

    public int? AssignedWorkstationID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public decimal FTE { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "tinyint")]
    public Byte? EmployeeRCD { get; set; }                  //  ADD 

    public virtual WorkStation WorkStation { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public virtual PayrollClass PayrollClass { get; set; }

    public virtual Position Position { get; set; }
}


public partial class EmployeePhoneNumber
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EmployeePhoneNumberID { get; set; }

    public int PhoneNumberTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(3)]
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(8)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [StringLength(7)]
    public string PhoneExtention { get; set; }

    [StringLength(25)]
    public string PhoneNumberNote { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public virtual LU_PhoneNumberTypes LU_PhoneNumberTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: EmployeePosition  and EmployeePhoneNumber don't happen to be structs, do they?

Comment: No, they are Entity Framework objects. I can post thier definitions on Monday